# How do I specify the correct defaultValue for Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER)?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm switching from the concept of a hard DATABASE reboot (sync({force:true})) to migrations.

When creating a migration ( nps sequelize-cl model:generate ... ) and then inserting it into the migration database ( npx sequelize-cli db:migrate), I get the following error:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 18.10.0, CLI: 6.6.0, ORM: 6.28.0]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
== 20230130114154-create-chat: migrating =======

ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[] DEFAULT , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMA' at line 1
```

My Migration file:

```
"use strict";
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable("Chat", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      user_ids: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER),
        defaultValue: [],
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("Chat");
  },
};
```

The problem is how the string defaultValue is recognized: []. [] - assumes not an array, but an array of values. For example, [0] is recognized as 0 for the default field, and an empty array as a void.

The question is how to specify the default value for the field:

```
... {
  type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER),
  defaultValue: ...,
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for the answer.

P.S. Somehow this problem was solved once, unfortunately the solution was not preserved.

Comment: According to the official docs ARRAY is supported only for PostgreSQL, see https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/other-data-types/#arrays-postgresql-only

Answer (score 0):

array is supported only for PostgreSQL

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array of integers then you can give the default value as per below:

`{ type: Sequelize.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER), defaultValue: [1] }`

and if it's an array of strings you can give default values like:

`{ type: Sequelize.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING), defaultValue: ['technician'] }`